# NiceMatrix \Block does not work with last-row option

Tags: nicematrix

I don't know whether it is a bug. The `\Block` command works well with `first-row` option, but with `last-row`, I got an error:
`You try to draw a block in the cell 3-1 of your matrix but the matrix is too small for that block. If you go on, this command will be ignored.`

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, last-row]
  \Block{1-2}{\text{test}}\\
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
  \Block{1-2}{\text{test}}\\
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: From the [documentation of `nicematrix`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/nicematrix/nicematrix.pdf), sec. 4, "The command `\Block` must be used in the upper leftmost cell of the array with two arguments." When option `last-row` is used, the last row is considered out of the array. Hence I suppose this is not.a bug. Though your question can still exist as a feature request.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Update

The desired usage is supported in `nicematrix`, v4.3 of 2020/06/12. See the [answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/549228) by package author
F. Pantigny.

#### Old

(Continued from my comment under question.)

If strictly follow the package documentation, `\Block` should not be supported in either first row nor last row. But it seems `nicematrix` supports `\Block` used in first row, but not last row. Maybe you can contact the package author.

As a workaround, you can use `\multicolumn` in last row.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{bNiceMatrix}[first-row, last-row]
  \Block{1-2}{\text{test}}\\
  a & b\\
  c & d\\
  \multicolumn{2}{C}{\text{test}}
\end{bNiceMatrix}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: I have contacted the author. This feature will come soon in the next version.

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck I've also appended a possible improvement code.

Answer (score 2):

The latest version of `nicematrix` (v 4.3 of 2020/06/12) solves that problem. It's now possible to use `\Block` in the last row. Moreover, the key `code-for-first-row` also applies in a `\Block` entirely in the first row and `code-for-last-row` applies in a `\Block` entirely in the last row.